# How to get this Method object via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

This is the class:

```
public class Foo {
  public void bar(Integer[] b) {
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to get this method via reflection:

```
Class cls = Foo.class;
Class[] types = { /* what is here */ };
cls.getMethod("bar", types);
```

How to create this "type"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Integer[].class` - this is the class literal for the integer array. If you need it dynamically, you can use `Class.forName("[Ljava.lang.Integer;")` as David noted.

If you don't know the exact types, you can call `getMethods()`, iterate the returned array and compare names.

Spring has an utility class `ReflectionUtils`, which have `findMethod(..)` that do this.

Comment: can I get this `Integer[].class` without an explicit static call? Imagine that I have `className = "Integer[]"`..

Comment: @yegor256 - This should do the trick, from [Java Reflection: Arrays](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/arrays.html#class): `"[Ljava.lang.Integer;"`

Comment: @yegor256 @David Harkness is correct, adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer[].class
```

blah blah blah blah blah blah

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit stupid that `Class` has no method to give the corresponding array class, only the other way around. Here is a workaround:

```
<E> public static Class<E[]> arrayClass(Class<E> elementClass) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Class<E[]> arrayClass = (Class<E[]>) Array.newInstance(elementClass, 0).getClass();
    return arrayClass;
}
```

With this method you could write

```
Class cls = Foo.class;
Class[] types = { arrayClass(Integer.class) };
cls.getMethod("bar", types);
```

Of course, if you can write `Integer.class`, you could also write `Integer[].class`. So this is only useful if you know your method takes an array of some class which you only get as a class object, otherwise use the answers given by Bozho.